# Auto viewPager in android

Tags: android-viewpager

I'm using viewpager library to implement image slider but don't know how to implement it to auto scroll. here is my code.
My code is error in mainActivity, ViewPageAdapter
I've been solving the problem for six hours. Please help me.

1.MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    internal lateinit var  viewpager :ViewPager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        viewpager = findViewById(R.id, viewpager) as ViewPager
        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(this)
        viewpager.adapter = adapter
    }

}
```

2.ViewPagerAdapter

```
    import android.content.Context
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.ImageView
    import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter
    import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    
    class ViewPagerAdapter(private val context: Context):PagerAdapter() {
        private var layoutInflater:LayoutInflater?=null
        var Image = arrayOf(
            R.drawable.imgview_1, R.drawable.imgview_2, R.drawable.imgview_3
        )
        override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean {
            return view===`object`
        }
    
        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return Image.size
    
        }
    
        override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
            layoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            val v = layoutInflater!!.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_activity, null)
            val image = v.findViewById<View>(R.id, imageview) as ImageView
            image.setImageResource(Image[position])
            val vp = container as ViewPager
            vp.addView(v, 0)
            return v;
        }
    
        override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
            val vp = container as ViewPager
            val v = `object` as View
            vp.removeView(v)
        }
    }
```

3.ViewPagerActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageview"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

4.activity_main

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/main_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably find it better to use [ViewFlipper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper) class instead as this can be set to auto switch between views and auto start on load.